# Building an Executable .jar file using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, build, jar, executable-jar

I've created a java project in Netbeans an am now stuck in the build stage. Everything in my project is set, I have a main class set in its properties and I even set my project as the main project. When I do a "Clean and Build", a dist folder is created with my .jar file. However, the .jar file is not executable, why? I opened the .jar file and looked at the manifest, a main class is specified, so what's the problem? I'm running Netbeans 7.3.1. Thanks.

Comment: How are you running it?  What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well when I double click the .jar file, Windows doesn't know what program to use to open it. So it opens up a dialog box for me to pick what program Windows should use.

Comment: That's not a problem with the Jar, that's a problem with Windows.  Try "browsing" to the installation location of your JRE and selecting `javaw.exe` to open it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer OMG thank you so much, how the heck could I have missed that? Anyways how can I have your comment as my accepted answer?

Comment: By having me put it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Well when I double click the .jar file, Windows doesn't know what
>   program to use to open it. So it opens up a dialog box for me to pick
>   what program Windows should use

The problem isn't with the Jar file but with Windows.  You need to register (preferably) `javaw.exe` as the default application to use when you want to open (double click) a Jar file.

When the dialog popups, browse to the installation location of your JRE and select `javaw.exe` from the `bin` folder...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the main class in Properties ---> Run--> Select MainClass

Comment: *"Everything in my project is set, I have a main class set in its properties and I even set my project as the main project"*...

Comment: Ya I've set a main class through the projects properties.

Comment: run the program using the path like as C:\Test : java -jar proj.jar and tell the output